# Populating prefillTabs before sending in nodejs SDK

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

How do we populate prefillTabs using docusign's nodejs sdk?
Here is the flow.I am failing at No. 5.

1. Fetch data from the projects database.
2. Docusign authentication to get **accountId**
3. Create envelope draft from template // {status: "created"} I can confirm that it is draft in my account.
4. Get the **envelopedId**.
5. use  envelopeAPI.createDocumentTabs with **accountId** and **envelopedId** to edit fields.

Here is the code. I am not sure if I am using the wrong API, but it is the closest I found. However it returns "Bad Request".

Here is my code that is failing :

```
    if (envelopeId) {
      console.log(accountId, envelopeId, tabs);
      const res = await envelopesApi
        .createDocumentTabs(accountId, envelopeId, '1', getTabs("hello"));
      console.log(res);
    }
```

I tried diffent format for the tabs here are some I tried at my getTabs(projName: string) funtion.

A)

```
    const prefillTabs = {
            textTabs: [
              {
                'anchorString': '/koujimei/',
                'anchorUnits': 'pixels',
                'anchorXOffset': '20',
                'anchorYOffset': '10',
                'scaleValue': '1.5',
                'name': 'projName',
                'value': projName,
              },
            ],
          };
          return JSON.stringify(prefillTabs)
```

B) This one matches the docs?

```
     const prefillTabs = {
        prefillTabs: {
          textTabs: [
            {
              'anchorString': '/koujimei/',
              'anchorUnits': 'pixels',
              'anchorXOffset': '20',
              'anchorYOffset': '10',
              'scaleValue': '1.5',
              'name': 'projName',
              'value': projName,
            },
          ],
        },
      };
   return JSON.stringify(prefillTabs);
```

C)

```
      const prefillTabs = {
        tabs: {
          prefillTabs: {
            textTabs: [
              {
                'anchorString': '/koujimei/',
                'anchorUnits': 'pixels',
                'anchorXOffset': '20',
                'anchorYOffset': '10',
                'scaleValue': '1.5',
                'name': 'projName',
                'value': projName,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      };
      return JSON.stringify(prefillTabs);
```

I also tried directly using the objects without stringify, but Typescript says it requires string.

Also docs say that 4th parameter is optional but it still fails "Bad Request".

```
const res = await envelopesApi
        .createDocumentTabs(accountId, envelopeId, '1');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please accept (check) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PreFill tabs [live example via the API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Prefill%20tabs) You can change the output language of the tool to the Node.SDK.

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
 // DocuSign API Request Builder example. Generated: Tue, 05 Jul 2022 20:44:20 GMT
 // DocuSign Ⓒ 2022. MIT License -- https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
'use strict';
const fse = require('fs-extra')
    , path = require('path')
    , docusign = require('docusign-esign')
    , baseUri = 'https://demo.docusign.net/'
      // Note: the accessToken is for testing and is temporary. It is only good for 8 hours from the time you 
      //       authenticated with API Request Builder. In production, use an OAuth flow to obtain access tokens.
    , accessToken = '..-7mT-4Gah3tduerH---...'
    , accountId = '...'
    , documentDirectory = '.'; // The directory with your documents
// Send the envelope
async function sendDocuSignEnvelope () {
    let signHereTab1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/sig1/",  
        anchorUnits: "pixels",  
        anchorXOffset: "20" 
        });
    let signHereTabs1 = [signHereTab1];
    let tabs1 = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        signHereTabs: signHereTabs1 
        });
    let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
        clientUserId: "1000",  
        email: "signer_email@example.com",  
        name: "Signer's name",  
        recipientId: "1",  
        tabs: tabs1 
        });
    let signers1 = [signer1];
    let recipients1 = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
        signers: signers1 
        });
    let textTab1 = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        bold: "true",  
        font: "Garamond",  
        fontColor: "BrightBlue",  
        fontSize: "Size14",  
        value: "This field and the following are all \"prefill\" fields: " 
        });
    let textTab2 = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        anchorXOffset: "0",  
        anchorYOffset: "30",  
        bold: "true",  
        font: "Garamond",  
        fontColor: "Black",  
        fontSize: "Size12",  
        value: "Checkbox:" 
        });
    let textTab3 = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        anchorXOffset: "90",  
        anchorYOffset: "30",  
        bold: "true",  
        font: "Garamond",  
        fontColor: "Black",  
        fontSize: "Size12",  
        value: "Radio button:" 
        });
    let textTab4 = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        anchorXOffset: "0",  
        anchorYOffset: "60",  
        bold: "true",  
        font: "Garamond",  
        fontColor: "Black",  
        fontSize: "Size12",  
        value: "Sender name:" 
        });
    let textTab5 = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        anchorXOffset: "190",  
        anchorYOffset: "60",  
        bold: "true",  
        font: "Garamond",  
        fontColor: "Black",  
        fontSize: "Size12",  
        value: "Sender company:" 
        });
    let textTabs1 = [textTab1, textTab2, textTab3, textTab4, textTab5];
    let checkboxTab1 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        anchorXOffset: "70",  
        anchorYOffset: "30",  
        fontSize: "Size14",  
        selected: "true" 
        });
    let checkboxTabs1 = [checkboxTab1];
    let radio1 = docusign.Radio.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/",  
        anchorXOffset: "185",  
        anchorYOffset: "30",  
        fontSize: "Size14",  
        selected: "true" 
        });
    let radios1 = [radio1];
    let radioGroupTab1 = docusign.RadioGroup.constructFromObject({
        radios: radios1 
        });
    let radioGroupTabs1 = [radioGroupTab1];
    let senderNameTab1 = docusign.SenderName.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        anchorXOffset: "90",  
        anchorYOffset: "58",  
        font: "Garamond",  
        fontColor: "DarkGreen",  
        fontSize: "Size12" 
        });
    let senderNameTabs1 = [senderNameTab1];
    let senderCompanyTab1 = docusign.SenderCompany.constructFromObject({
        anchorString: "/field1/ ",  
        anchorXOffset: "310",  
        anchorYOffset: "58",  
        font: "Garamond",  
        fontColor: "DarkGreen",  
        fontSize: "Size12" 
        });
    let senderCompanyTabs1 = [senderCompanyTab1];
    let prefillTabs1 = docusign.PrefillTabs.constructFromObject({
        checkboxTabs: checkboxTabs1,  
        radioGroupTabs: radioGroupTabs1,  
        senderCompanyTabs: senderCompanyTabs1,  
        senderNameTabs: senderNameTabs1,  
        textTabs: textTabs1 
        });
    let tabs2 = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        prefillTabs: prefillTabs1 
        });
    let document1 = docusign.Document.constructFromObject({
        documentId: "1",  
        fileExtension: "pdf",  
        documentBase64: await readDocFileB64("anchorfields.pdf"),  // filename is anchorfields.pdf
        name: "Example document",  
        tabs: tabs2 
        });
    let documents1 = [document1];
    let envelopeDefinition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition.constructFromObject({
        documents: documents1,  
        emailSubject: "Please sign the attached document",  
        recipients: recipients1,  
        status: "sent" 
        });
 
    try {
        const dsApi = new docusign.ApiClient();
        dsApi.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        dsApi.setBasePath(baseUri + 'restapi');
        const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApi);
        const envResults = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, 
            {envelopeDefinition: envelopeDefinition});
        console.log (`Create envelope results: ${JSON.stringify(envResults, null, '    ')}`);
        console.log (`The envelopeId is ${envResults.envelopeId}`);
        return envResults.envelopeId;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log (`Error from DocuSign create envelope: ` +
           `${(e && e.response && JSON.stringify(e.response.body))||e}`);
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I had problems accessing query builder, but they fixed it for me. Thanks!  It worked.